# TCP socket programming between two 64bit machines

Tags: c, sockets

I am trying to implemante a client- server program communication using TCP socket programming in C. 
It is between between two 64bit machines with linux OS installed.
I want to transfer a c-struct between the two processes.

For this I try used a pack - unpack() functioanlity.

please consider the following code snipt

```
/*---------------------------------------------------------
on the sending side I have: 
---------------------------------------------------------*/

struct packet {
 int64_t x;
 int64_t y;
 int64_t q[maxSize];
} __attribute__((packed));

int main(void)
{
 // build packet
 struct packet pkt;
 pkt.x = htonl(324);
 pkt.y = htonl(654);
 int i;
 for(i = 0; i< maxSize; i++){
    pkt.q[i] = i; **// I also try pkt.q[i] = htonl(i);**
 }
  // and then do the send
}

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 in the receiving side: 
 -----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
struct packet {
 int64_t x;
 int64_t y;
 int64_t q[maxSize];
} __attribute__((packed));

static void decodePacket (uint8_t *recv_data, size_t recv_len)
{
 // checking size
 if (recv_len < sizeof(struct packet)) {
     fprintf(stderr, "received too little!");
     return;
 }

struct packet *recv_packet = (struct packet *)recv_data;

int64_t x = ntohl(recv_packet->x);
int64_t y = ntohl(recv_packet->y);
int i;
printf("Decoded: x=%"PRIu8" y=%"PRIu32"\n", x, y);

 for(i=0;i<maxSize;i++){
  **//int64_t res = ntohl(recv_packet->q[i]);  I also try to print res**          
  printf("%"PRIu32"\n" , recv_packet->q[i]);     
 }
} 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
 // receive the data and try to call decodePacket()
 int8_t *recv_data = (int8_t *)&buf; //buf is the data received
 size_t recv_len = sizeof(buf);
 **decode_packet(recv_data, recv_len);**  
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now the problem is that I am receiving the value of x and y in the struct correctly, 
but for the array q in the struct I am receiving a strange number, possible a memory grabage value, (I try to use memset() filling the array by zeros before receiving a data from the other side in which case the value of all zeros is received )

I don't understand why I am not receiving the correct value for the array in struct.

**Please Note** that I try with and with out htonl() while filling the array before putting in struct, 
and on the other side: with and with out ntohl() while decoding the array from struct

Any help will be appreciated,

Comment: You have several mismatched print formats in your receive side - that will cause undefined behaviour.  Fix those and try again?

Comment: Since the problem is likely to be in either the sending or receiving code, you have omitted the bits that matter. One possibility is that the structure needs to be declared as packed at both end (depending on how you are trying to send/receive it).

Comment: Yeah. And this won't even work between two Linuxes where the compiler inserts deifferent paddings. You'd better serialise the values. Don't even try to directly transfer structs.

Comment: What's the value of `maxSize` (is it the same on both sides?), and do you check the return value of `write(2)`/`send(2)`?

Comment: @H2CO3, the struct has `__attribute__((packed))`, so no padding.

Comment: yes you all guys are correct it was the send() function, I was sending few bytes and trying to receive all of it, my mistake.
thank you all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> size_t recv_len = sizeof(buf);
> decode_packet(recv_data, recv_len);
> ```

This piece of code ensures the wrong size is passed to `decode_packet`. So when `decode_packet` goes on to check `recv_len < sizeof(struct packet)`, that test is meaningless - **it will always pass, no matter how many bytes were received**.

You need to fetch the size from the value returned by the `recv` call. My best guess is that indeed you're receiving fewer bytes than you're expecting.

---

While sending and receiving structs is quite convenient, it's often an exercise in futility. Manually serializing data or using some explicit mechanisms is probably the way to go.

Comment: Your guess was correct, I was sending few bytes and trying to receive all of it, my mistake. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show us the `send` and `recv` part, which is more likely to be wrong. My guess is you're receiving first items in the array correctly and they "become" garbage at some point, is it right?

Well, @cnicutar is correct, but let me extend it a little bit...

First of all, when you call `send` you have to examine the return value and see if all bytes have been transmitted. If your structure is large (for example larger than underlying socket buffer) you'll need more than one call to transmit the whole structure. Same with `recv`, **don't expect you will get the whole message in one `recv` call**, don't expect every `recv` will receive the same amount of data that was sent by corresponding `send` call. Always check how many bytes have been received and call `recv` again if necessary (pointing to the right place in incoming buffer and reducing number of bytes to receive).

So what is probably happening, you don't receive enough data (maybe you don't even transmit all of it) and only beginning of your incoming buffer is being filled. Therefore, the rest of the structure is garbage or (when you call `memset`) stays initialised with zeros.

Also note both `send` and `recv` return `ssize_t` rather than `size_t` as negative values are possible (to indicate errors).

Comment: Your are correct, I was sending few bytes and trying to receive all of it, my mistake. Thanks for your help